# C Negation Operator Prints Unexpected Results In Debian Terminal

Tags: c, gdb

This is purely academic but I've created a simple truth table in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for(int j=0; j<=2; j++) {
    int bitB = (j&1);
    printf("~%d = %d\n", bitB, ~bitB);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Running in terminal yields:

```
~1 = -2
~0 = -1
```

Debugging in gdb by setting a break on printf yields what I'd expect, however:

```
(gdb) print bitB
$5 = 1
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
~1 = -2
(gdb) x/xw &bitB
0xbffff3d8: 0x00000000
```

Why is the program output showing negative numbers?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code shown will not produce this output. And the question does not make any sense. You compare apples and oranges? `x/xw` is a completely different command with diferent output. Why don't you `p ~bitb` like in your code?

Comment: Look up two's complement and how negative integers are represented.

Comment: Adjusting for 2's complement:

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for(int j=0; j<=1; j++) {
    unsigned int bitB = (j&1);
    printf("~%d=%u\n",bitB,~(bitB - 2);
  }
  return 0;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfectly expected result, at least on systems where negative numbers are represented in [two's complement system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement):

- Negative one is represented with all bits set to `1`, and
- Negative two has all bits set to `1` except the last bit.

Hence, flipping all bits of zero yields `-1`, and flipping all bits of `1` yields `-2`:

```
0000000000000000 -> 1111111111111111 // Zero becomes negative 1
0000000000000001 -> 1111111111111110 // One becomes negative 2
```

Mathematically, to flip the sign of a number in two's complement representation you flip all bits of the number, and then add `1` to the result. Simply flipping all bits of `x` yields `-x-1`. This is precisely the result that you see.

> Why is the program output showing negative numbers?

Because you use signed `int` with `%d` format specifier, and the bit patterns that you print happen to be representations of negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

On all systems and number representations this will give negative numbers. You are complementing all bits, including the sign bit.

Answer (score -1):

Because you use the type `int` (containing its sign), and inverting the highest bit also changes the sign according to [Two's complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) rules (note that `~` inverts/complements all bits).

You probably want to use `unsigned int` (and `%u`), if you expect that `~` gives you the representation without sign.